# network bridge between ethernet adapter and wifi adapter on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, ethernet, adapter

I want to establish a network bridge between the ethernet network adapter and the WIFI network adapter in an Ubuntu 22.04. I need both to be on the same network so that any device connected to the WIFI access point can access the devices on the wired network and vice versa, without an Internet connection and all with static IPv4, without a DHCP server. I've searched the internet and can't find any solution. Help!

Comment: A bridge requires different networks. What problem so you have (or expect) with different networks? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: What is your access point? Normally an access point (like your Internet router) with Wireless and Ethernet connection will do this automatically.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1478604/edit) and answer all the question we ask in the comments. A network bridge by definition means two (or more) networks. You say you need both Ethernet and WiFi to be in the same network. This is a contradiction. Please add more information about your planned network. How many devices will connect to the Ubuntu computer via Ethernet? How many via WiFi? Will any of these devices (including the Ubuntu computer) get connected to the Internet? Is so, how?

Comment: Solved it with hostapd! Thanks everybody anyway!